# How can I convert a column of hours / minutes with varying digits into datetime objects in python/pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I am trying to create a single datetime column on pandas from two Dataframe columns one which has the date and the other which has the time.

They are in the following format:

```
Date       Time
20110101    53
20110102   253
20110103   653
20110104  1053
```

I thought of converting them both to strings like so:

```
df_shortened["datetime"] = df_shortened['date'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')  + " " + df_shortened['Time'].astype(str)
```

getting strings like this...

```
0          2011-01-01 53
1         2011-01-01 153
2         2011-01-01 253
3         2011-01-01 353
4         2011-01-01 453
```

And then trying to convert the resulting column into a datetime object like this...

```
df["dtcolumn"] = pd.to_datetime(df["dtcolumn"], format='%Y%m%d %H%M')
```

Which did not work. I assume it is because of the varying number  of digits, I'm not sure.

```
ValueError: time data '2011-01-01 53' does not match format '%Y%m%d %H%M' (match)
```

If I coerce errors it just leaves it as a string. How do I solve it? Do I need to pad the numbers which are shorter? How does it recognize hours from minutes?

Comment: What does Time 53 mean? 253 mean?  Are those 00:53 and 02:53?

Comment: Yeah I guess. like 00:53

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this using `zfill` and string manipulation:

```
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'].astype(str) + ' ' + 
                                df['Time'].astype(str).str.zfill(4), format='%Y%m%d %H%M')
```

Output:

```
       Date  Time            datetime
0  20110101    53 2011-01-01 00:53:00
1  20110102   253 2011-01-02 02:53:00
2  20110103   653 2011-01-03 06:53:00
3  20110104  1053 2011-01-04 10:53:00
```